# Jquery - divs animate one after the other despite queue false

Tags: jquery

I have two divs that I'm wanting to animate at the same time.  Despite using queue false the divs animate one after the other:

```
$('.button_top, .button_bottom').click(function() {
    $('.button_bottom').animate({marginTop: "+100px"}, {duration: 500, queue: false});
    $('.button_top').animate({marginTop: "-50px"}, {
    duration: 500, 
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {
opened = true;
    }
    }); 
if(opened == true){
    $('.button_bottom').animate({marginTop: "0px"}, {duration: 500, queue: false});
    $('.button_top').animate({marginTop: "+50px"}, {
    duration: 500, 
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {
opened = false;
    }
});
}
});
```

See fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/hBqfQ/

Note that the divs animate together the first time, but not when clicked the second time or afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change your code to animate almost any property but `marginTop`, you'll see that it animates properly: `marginLeft`, `width`, etc. all work.

The problem is that as you animate the `marginTop` of the upper button, you affect thereby the position of the lower button (since changing the `marginTop` of the upper button affects the space it occupies in the layout). You can see this more clearly if you change the second animation definition to, say, `$('.button_bottom').animate({marginTop: "25px"}, {duration: 500, queue: false});`  (Or at least that's the closest I can come to an answer. If this is right, I'm not sure why the below solution works.)

Now, I'm a bit fuzzy as to why precisely this fixes it, but if you change the second animation to the following, then your problem goes away:

```
$('.button_bottom').animate({marginTop: "0px"}, {duration: 500, queue: false});

$('.button_top').animate({marginTop: "0px"}, {
    duration: 500, 
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {
    opened = false;
}
```

See **[this working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/7WExA/1/)**.